# How do you mock a single file in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I want to test a function which opens multiple files using `open` calls, but I want to mock out *one* of those calls.

I've tried using the [mock_open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open) method but it mocks all calls to `open`, not specific files.

*What is the best way to mock the read data from only a single file in python?*

Comment: Could you expand with some context?

Comment: Sure, thanks for looking! For example, the function under test might first open A.txt, do something, then open B.txt. The real A.txt might be OK to use under test, so doesn't need mocking out. But B.txt needs mocking to test the function fully.  A common way to mock out files being read is to use mock_open, but It seems this mocks all files - meaning that it mocks A.txt as well as B.txt. Our current workaround is to move the opening of B.txt to a separate method and mock that method out, however this isn't always clean or possible.

Comment: What if you set a function that handle some context on `return_value` of mock definition? If file match some condition, return a mock, else the original file.